# Bob smith termination - Working

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors, ethernet

I've seen a couple of questions on Bob-smith termination for Ethernet magnetics.

But I fail to understand why the bob-smith termination is required?

Like, what's the purpose and how does the termination help to do what is required? Any value of RC is fine?

Since, I'm a freshman, can someone explain this is simple terms?

Comment: What do you understand about transmission lines and termination, before applying that to the context of Ethernet? Just to make a better answer. So whether the question is about any transmission lines, or how does relate to more complex case for Ethernet, which has multiple pairs of transmission lines, and galvanic isolation with transformers.

Comment: I understand that transmission lines are a combination of small inductors and capacitors. Any trace/signals is actually a combination of L and C.

Comment: @Freshman May want to skim [this](https://www.edn.com/updating-the-bob-smith-termination-technique/). It's a starting point.